# Why are my documents being deleted?

Tags: windows-10, file-recovery

I just updated to Windows 10 and it deleted all my files from before (my music, documents, pictures- everything.) Now I don't know how to get it to save my new pictures and Word Documents.

My computer said that I needed to log in but I thought I was already logged in, I mean I entered my password and everything. So my questions are:

- Is it possible for me to recover the files from before the update?
- Is it possible for me to recover the files I had before I turned my computer off?
- How do I get my computer to save my files?

Comment: I actually encountered a similar problem with one of my customers today. The windows 10 upgrade process did convert the profile as it should, but the profile could not be loaded and instead a new profile called TEMP was created and the files were obviously in the other profile folder. You should be able to find your files in C:\Users\<username>\Documents. I fixed it by simply restarting the computer. Might work for you as well.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!! You were completely right!

Answer (score 1):

Turned the comment into an answer as it seems it was the case for you as well.

---

I actually encountered a similar problem with one of my customers today. The windows 10 upgrade process did convert the profile as it should, but the profile could not be loaded and instead a new profile called TEMP was created and the files were obviously in the other profile folder. You should be able to find your files in `C:\Users\<username>\Documents`. I fixed it by simply restarting the computer. Might work for you as well